# Is there any replacement of @redux-dynostore?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have upgraded my React-Redux version to 7.x.x. However, the @redux-dynostore is giving an error. Is it any replacement of @redux-dynostore?

Comment: I've the same issue when i tried to upgrade the react-redux version to 7.1.0 redux-dynostore is failing.

Answer (score 0):

The `@redux-dynostore/react-redux` package looks like [it expects to work fine with React-Redux v7](https://github.com/ioof-holdings/redux-dynostore/blob/1082c41bc5217f1b905c47024fa9ce84ccd5ee66/packages/redux-dynostore-react-redux/package.json#L32).